# Formatting Source Data for Running-Coder/jquery-typeahead to Return Selected Item ID

Tags: php, jquery, typeahead.js

I have the [Running-Coder/jQuery](https://github.com/running-coder/jquery-typeahead/issues) version of typeahead working in a limited fashion but I need help in structuring the ajax data to return a format that will allow me to access the index of the selected item.

For example the following code works fine

```
function milestoneTypeAheadLookUp () {
             $.typeahead({
                input: '.ms-typeahead',
                minLength: 1,
                order: "asc",
                offset: false,
                cancelButton: false,
                hint: true,
                source: {
                        ajax: {
                            type: "POST",
                            url: 'data/MilestoneData.php',
                            data: {
                             keyword: "null"
                            }
                    }
                },
                callback: {
                    onClick: function (node, a, item, event) {
                        console.log(node)

                    },
                    onSubmit: function (node, form, item, event) {

                        console.log(node)
                    }
                }
            });
    }
```

with a simple php data set such as

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo  json_encode(
    array("Milesone 1", "Milestone 2","Milestone 3","Milestone 4")
);
```

Which is not very helpful as I really need to pass an associative array to typeahead, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do it.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I have found during this exercise is that there are myriad `autocomplete` and `typeahead` implementations out there with some being very complex and difficult to find working examples that are relevant to your particular case.

After spending too much time on this I finally came across and simple implementation of an autocomplete javascript library that proved very easy to modify which you can add to your own library.  It is located at the [W3 Schools site](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp).   The only modification I have made is to implement a callback to pass the selected item and a small modification to the code so that a proper JSON array can be parsed.
For example

```
function autocomplete(inp, arr, callback) {
 .....
}
```

The `arr` argument has the form:

```
var countries = [{"index":"6", "name":"Afghanistan"}, {"index":"8","name":"Albania"}];
```

Where the name and index elements of the `arr` arguments are now accessed (within autocomplete.js) as

```
arr[i].name and arr[i].index
```

respectively.  The selected values are then easily return as a JSON object as part of the callback data.